# is there a different method to use useEffect in next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-hooks

So I have written a react code that when ever i scroll down a neon line goes from the top of the page to the bottom of the page the probleme is whene i tryied it on next.js it dosn't work and the erorr is neonLine is null any clue why ?

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./Neon.module.css";
const Neon = () => {
  const [scrolling, setScrolling] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      setScrolling(true);
      const neonLine = document.querySelector(".nLine");
      const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
      const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
      const documentHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
      const scrollPercentage = (scrollTop / (documentHeight - windowHeight)) * 100;
      neonLine.style.height = scrollPercentage + "%";
    };
    let scrollingTimeout;
    const checkScrollStop = () => {
      if (scrolling) {
        setScrolling(false);
        clearTimeout(scrollingTimeout);
      } else {
        const neonLine = document.querySelector(".nLine");
        neonLine.style.transition = "height 0.5s ease-in-out";
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", checkScrollStop);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", checkScrollStop);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className={styles.con}>
      <div className={styles.neon}></div>
      <div className={styles.line}>
        <div className={styles["nLine"]}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Neon;
```

Comment: You want to use the useRef hook learn more about it here -> https://upmostly.com/tutorials/how-to-react-useref-hook

Answer (score 0):

You have:

> ```
> className={styles["nLine"]}
> ```

and

> ```
> const neonLine = document.querySelector(".nLine");
> ```

You are assuming that the value of `styles["nLine"]` will be `"nLine"`.

This is an incorrect assumption. The class names are randomised for uniqueness so that  you can use the same name in different components without them conflicting and having each other's styles applied to them.

---

In general, you should avoid direct DOM access. When you need access to the DOM, use [a reference](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) instead of searching the whole DOM.

```js
const ref = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      setScrolling(true);
      const neonLine = ref.current;
...
    <div ref={ref} className={styles["nLine"]}></div>
```